# How to make a masked part emit light to the object itself

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, lighting, shader-nodes

I have a little problem that I can't solve.

I have applied a black and white mask to my material, where the white part emits light.

When I mix the base material with the mask, it is applied correctly and emits light, but I can't get it to emit light to the object itself since it is a low poly model, so the whole area is flat.

How could I make it emit light to the model itself having as light sources only the parts of the object itself that shine? I leave you some images for a better understanding:

This is what I want to achieve, it is an example found on the internet:
[image]

And this is what I have:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I want that red part that I have masked to also emit light to the object itself (it's a flat door),
but it doesn't do it even if I increase the light intensity by hundreds.

Can you think of a practical and efficient way to do it? I've tried adding the same plane by moving it just to the side so that it emits light to the door itself, but the light and shadows are not very good.

Thanks for your time!